# How to use more than one conda environment in a project

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, environment

I am working on a research project in which I need to use some scientific packages each of which comes with their specific requirement files including their needed libraries. I am coding python in jupyter notebook using Anaconda in Windows 10.

Based on what I've read on the web, each project needs to have its own environment, so I created an environment (say project_env) using conda. During my project, in some parts, I need to use some external scientific packages (let's call 'bst' and 'MDN'), cloned from Github, each of which has their specific dependencies.

my current practice is just installing all these dependencies in the same environment (project_env), and code the whole project in one notebook. However, as going forward, things getting more complicated and facing some conflicts between installed packages even using conda installation. So, I came up with this idea to keep things apart as much as possible, i.e. creating two other environments for the external packages (bst_env and MDN_env) and then using them whenever I need them in the project. Under this scenrio, I cannot include all my project code in one jupyter notebook because as far as I know there is no way to switch between environments from inside a notebook. However, in this way it is quite difficult and messy to run different notebooks for different parts of the project.

My question is: Is there a method to run more than one environment from a notebook? if no, what would be the best practice to handle these environments in a project? should I export my variables from my source code (run in project_env) to other environments (bst_env or MDN_env) every time and activate and run their according environments and notebooks every time or there is a better practice to do that?

Comment: _facing some conflicts between installed packages even using conda installation_ We might be able to help with that part.

Answer (score 0):

I found this great package (nb_conda_kernels), which is exactly what I wanted. It enables you to switch between environments (kernels) inside a jupyter notebook, just by selecting from a list of available environments.

As mentioned here (https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels), just type:  'conda install nb_conda_kernels' in conda terminal to install this package in the environment (kernel) from which you want to run other environments (kernels). In my case (the above question) it is 'project_env'. Also, make sure to have 'ipykernel' installed in the external environments you want to use in your notebook (in my case: 'bst_env' and 'MDN_env').

Now, during working in a notebook under environment "A", you can use dependencies installed in environments "B" or "C" just by selecting these environments from the list of kernels in jupyter notebook.